# HTML <input> & <button> browser inconsistency

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

**fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/63rfLkgg/2/ (code is here)

The following CSS renders differently on Firefox, Chrome and IE:

```
input, button {
    min-height: 32px;
    min-width: 32px;
    background-color: #AAA;
    color: #444;
    line-height: 32px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

**On Firefox:** The button is 34px tall instead of 32.

**On Chrome:** The text fields are 37px tall instead of 32.

**On IE:** Same as chrome, but goes insane when i remove `vertical-align: middle;`.

***Why are all these things happening?***

**EDIT:**

The issues on Chrome and IE can easilly be fixed by adding `vertical-align: middle;` and `height: 32px;`, but i still wonder why the issues even exist in the first place.

Comment: Make sure you have reset settings and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing - Box-sizing

Comment: @Riskbreaker "Make sure you have reset settings" what do you mean?
"developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing - Box-sizing" Already tried that, doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have this in your global? http://cssreset.com/

Comment: @Riskbreaker now i do... nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok heres what I did:

[Box-Sizing for the win](https://jsfiddle.net/63rfLkgg/5/)

So What I did is for button I added:

```
button {box-sizing: content-box;}
```

and for input I did:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

I also got rid of the line-height and added 'Login' on the input so you can see it looks the same in spacing.

heres a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Removing the line-height fixes the button height, wich is expected because 0px+2px is less than 32px... but then i can't make buttons with multiple lines of text. The problem is that firefox adds 2px to the height of whatever's inside the button.

Comment: oh Mozilla...might have to explore -moz on this one